# Connecting microSD reader and e-paper display to Nano at the same time?

Tags: arduino-nano, sd-card, display, arduino-micro

Pretty much as the question states, I'm wondering if it's possible to connect (this: https://www.waveshare.com/7.5inch-HD-e-Paper-HAT.htm ) 7.5" e-paper display that has raspberry pi HAT and an SD card reader to Arduino nano/micro for reading images off SD and displaying on the screen. I'm an novice and a not sure if i can use the same pins for multipurpose

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the warning about the Arduino Uno on that page? This goes for the Nano as well. That said, yes, it's probably technically possible.if you can find a suitable library and you can overcome the memory limits stated on the product page and the fact that you have to share the SPI bus between two devices. I really don't recommend it for a novice. You're probably better of with a shield designed for and supported by the Arduino.

Comment: The SPI sharing part is the one that I'm mostly confused about. Also if i go with a shield, that would limit me to arduino UNO

Comment: The physical difference between Uno and Nano is the least problem. RAM problem already inhibits using a Nano/Uno with that 880×528 display. Using an SD reader alone takes at least half of the Uno/Nano RAM. A Jetson Nano is *not* an Arduino Nano.

Comment: What would be the ideal solution (not limited to arduino) to use the display and sd card together, using least amount of power, meaning no power wasted on any other processes?

Comment: Sharing an SPI bus should not be a problem If you design it well. The MISO, MOSI, and SCLKs can be connected to both devices, the Chip Selects (CS) need to be separate. This is the way many commercially available shields (for example the Arduino Ethernet shield with Ethernet / SD card or many TFT shields with TFT / Touch interface and SD card combined on one SPI bus) work,

Answer (score 0):

No. Even the e-Paper alone is not usable by an Arduino Nano.